# Segmentation in SAS

Tags: sas, segment

I have a dataset on a portfolio and wanted to some segmentation in SAS. A portion of the dataset looks like the following:

```
ID Var1   Prod      Date      Balance

1    10       L1    Jul-09        200  
1    10       L2    Aug-09        300  
2    5      L1.1    Aug-09       -150  
2    5        L3    Sep-09        200
```

I want to create segmentation based on values from `Prod` (e.g. `L1`, `L2`, etc). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation in the context you provided is a bit ambiguous. If by that you mean to create segmented *datasets*, each having observations associated with a unique value from `Prod`, you might be able to use the code from [here](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2015/01/26/how-to-split-one-data-set-into-many/):

```
/* define which libname.member table, and by which column */
%let TABLE=sashelp.cars;
%let COLUMN=origin;

proc sql noprint;
/* build a mini program for each value */
/* create a table with valid chars from data value */
select distinct 
   cat("DATA out_",compress(&COLUMN.,,'kad'),
   "; set &TABLE.(where=(&COLUMN.='", &COLUMN.,
   "')); run;") into :allsteps separated by ';' 
  from &TABLE.;
quit;

/* macro that includes the program we just generated */
%macro runSteps;
 &allsteps.;
%mend;

/* and...run the macro when ready */
%runSteps;
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with segmentation, but can you use a class statement?

Comment: This is probably more appropriate as a comment rather than an answer.